# LC3 assembly language to read one digit

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have an LC3 language assignment to input a single two digit decimal number and output the sum. For example

> number inputted: 23.
>   number outputted: 5.

Now, what I did is I wrote the program except it reads in the digits in separate lines, so for example

> num 1 inputted    (=2)
>   num 2 inputted    (=3)
>   num outputted: 5

I have pasted my code below for reference but I was wondering if anyone could help me fix my problem. I have no idea where to start so any advice would be much appreciated!

```
.ORIG X3000
;INPUTS TWO NUMBERS
IN                ;inputs first char
LD R3,HEXN30      ;subtract x30 to get int
ADD R0,R0,R3      
ADD R1,R0,X0      ;move first int to reg 1
IN                ;inputs second char
ADD R0,R0,R3      ;convert it to int
ADD R2,R0,R1      ;add the two ints
                                          ;PRINT RESULTS
LEA R0,MSG        ;loads address of msg strng
PUTS              ;to output the strng
ADD R0,R2,x0      ;move sum to reg 0, for output
LD R2, NTEN       ;load -10 into reg 2 
ADD R2,R2,R0      ;subtract 10 from sum
LD R3,HEX30       ;add 30 to int to get char
ADD R0,R0,R3
OUT               ;display sum

HALT

;**************DATA*******************

  MSG .STRINGZ "the sum of the 2 numbers is: "
  HEXN30 .FILL xFFD0                              ;-30 hex
  HEX30  .FILL x0030                              ;30 hex
  NTEN   .FILL #-10                               ;-10 dec
  ASCII1 .FILL x0031                              ;1 ascii    
.END
```

Comment: Don't use `IN`. Maybe use `GETC` and `PUTC`. You'll also have to print our own prompt message for the inputs.

Comment: I understand why I should use PUTC but why should I use GETC?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what your problem is you're describing or what it is you are wanting to do. Are you saying you want to run the program and have it look like the first example, so you enter 23 to add up 2 and 3?